# Validating constructor parameter and lint error

Tags: oop, typescript, tslint

I'm trying to validate a constructor parameter when creating an instance of a class.

The parameter should be an object containing **exactly** all the properties (of adequate type) as defined in the class.

If this is not the case, I'd like TypeScript to lint the mismatch.

```
class User {
    username: string;
    // more properties

    constructor(data:object) {
        // Check if data Obejct exactly all the class properties and they are of the right type;
        // Set instance properties
    }
};

// Desired Output
new User(); // "data parameter missing";
new User(45); // "data parameter is not of type object";
new User(); // "username Poperty missing!";
new User({username:"Michael"}); // Valid;
new User({username:43}); // "username is not of type string";
new User({username:"Michael", favoriteFood: "Pizza"}); // "favoriteFood is not a valid property";
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2016.array.include"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is declaring an interface :

```
interface UserProps {
  username: string;
}

class User implements UserProps {
  username: string;
  // more properties

  constructor (data: UserProps) {
    // Check if data Obejct exactly all the class properties and they are of the right type;
    // Set instance properties
  }
}
```

Comment: Did so, but my IDE (Intellij IDEA) still doesn't lint a mismatch.
Using an Interface makes sense (especially declaring in the constructor), but I still have to define the properties in the Interface and the Class, is there no cleaner way for achieving this?

Comment: I guess you have typescript syntax checker configured for your project ?

Comment: Not sure about that, I've added my `tsconfiig,json` file to the question

Comment: Check Settings → Languages & Frameworks → Typescript and assert that `Use Typescript Service` is checked

Comment: If there is not such menu you should add typescript plugin from intellij-idea plugin store.

Comment: It is checked. I also have `tslint` installed but no 'tslint.json`file

Comment: `tslint` is not necessary for type errors and that should be one. Here is the feedback your IDE should provide (working on webstorm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SkLAIP-_FXVvMJfbRmRYXcSG2UYl8sTc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also assert that 
1. `Use tsconfig.json` is checked
2. your ts file is in a non-excluded folder project
3. your tsfile is detected as Typescript file (should see a TS logo next to your filename in your project file hierarchy view)

Comment: 2 and 3 is given, how can I make sure that `tsconfig.json` is used?

Comment: That would be in Settings → Languages & Frameworks → Typescript

Comment: Seems like I habe no idea about TypeScript, so I gotta dive into it now. Do you have an idea how I could avoid defining the properties only in the interface, but no as well in the class?

Comment: Well this is how Typescript interface work ; classes won't inherit properties from `implementing` interfaces, they will just hold the contract that they have such properties or methods...
Your IDE will provide you a good help with `ALT+F4` and select "implement all members" intent when selecting class name ; it will define all properties derived from the interface.

Comment: And good luck with TS, it's a wonderful tool and I hope you'll enjoy learning it as I have !

Comment: Sorry, `ALT+Enter`